# When using a regex in iron router, how to access the match?

Tags: regex, meteor, iron-router

Rather than having five different routes, I am trying to combined five different paths into a single function, but I still need to know which path it matched. So if I set up my route using a regex:

```
Router.route(/^\/(accounts)|(contacts)|(forecasts)|(analytics)|(activities)/, function() {
    // which one did it match?
    console.log("matched "+this.params) //this returns an array of five params
}
```

how do I refer to the matched parameter inside the function?

this.params returns an array of five params with four of them undefined and the other matching, but which one is defined depends on what matched so this isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical scenario for Iron.Router custom route controller! Check the guide [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#creating-route-controllers) If you need some code, let me know. ;)

**[Edit]**

1. First, you define a route controller for all your sites, which inherit
   from the RouteController.

   ```
   BaseController = RouteController.extend({
       // Put repeating logic for your sites here
   });
   ```
2. After that, you define your routes seperatly, not via regex. This is
   much more modular and maintainable. The big point here is, you don't
   have to find out by complicated functions, which site is current.

   ```
   Router.map(function(){
       this.route('accounts', {
           path: '/accounts'
       });
   });
   ```
3. Now, give your routes his own controller

   ```
   Router.map(function(){
       this.route('accounts', {
           path: '/accounts',
           controller: 'AccountsController'
       });
   });
   ```
4. In this Example, your `AccountsController` needs to inherit from your
   new `BaseController`. Put all your route logic, which is specific
   for only this route, in your `AccountsController`

   ```
   AccountsController = BaseController.extend({
       // Put your specific route logic here
   });
   ```
5. Make sure, your `BaseController` is loading by meteor before your
   routes. Check out Meteor [File Load Order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).You can do something like the following

   ```
   client/routes
   client/routes/routes.js
   client/routes/controller/AccountsController.js
   client/routes/controller/BaseController.js
   ```

Comment: can you expand on this a little? I did check the guide but I'm not sure how using a custom route controller helps here.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, and I see how this is a better structure in many ways. I may go there going forward, but what I should have mentioned is that I'm using the regex matching for boilerplate code in a prototype. Instead of a catch-all route, I know upfront which routes are valid, but they all use the same stub. Eventually, I may move some of these paths out of there when I fill in that part of the app, but in the beginning I want something that doesn't need a lot of code and can easily be added to/removed from, hence the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this.params after all by rewriting the regex as follows:

```
Router.route(/^\/(accounts|contacts|forecasts|analytics|activities)/, function() {
    console.log('matched: '+this.params[0]);
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to refer to a regex match tho.

Comment: Why not use 5 different routes? This seems like a less readable version of the same thing.

Comment: Because in the final version there would be a lot of repeated logic inside the different routes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to use a loop to define several routes.

```
_.each(["accounts", "contacts", "forecasts"], function (path) {
  Router.route(path, function () {
    // inside here you can reference path
  });
});
```

Using one route with many unrelated paths seems like a hack to me.