# Meteor's Iron Router - Route multiple paths to one template but still DRY

Tags: meteor, routes, dry, iron-router

I want to route multiple paths to the same template. For example, `/abc/home` and `/home` will both show the `home` template. The paths can also have subpaths, so `abc/parent/child` and `/parent/child` should route to same path also.

---

1. I can **simply repeat**:

   ```
   Router.route('/home', function () {
     this.render('home');
     Session.set('menu', 'home');
   });
   Router.route('/abc/home', function () {
     this.render('home');
     Session.set('menu', 'home');
   });
   ```

But I don't want to repeat it. If I want to change the template to route to, I want to only change it once - for convenience and also to minimize errors.

---

2. I can also use **parameters**:

   ```
   Router.route('/:_abc/:path', function () {
     if(this.params._abc == 'abc') {
       switch(this.params.path) {
         case 'home':
           this.render('home');
           break;
         case 'someotherroute':
           this.render('someotherroute');
           break;
       }
     }
   });
   ```

But this, again, is repeating myself. Also, there can subpaths, and I don't want to define routing for `/:_abc/:parent/:children` and `/:_abc/:grandparent/:parent/:children/:`, because it will be messy.

---

3. I also tried using **`Router.go()`**:

   ```
   Router.route('/:_abc/:route', function () {
     if(this.params._abc == 'abc') {
       Router.go('/' + this.params.route);
     }
   });
   ```

But this removes the `/abc/` from the url, which is undesired in my case.

---

4. The best solution I have right now is using a **shared function**:

   ```
   var renderHome = function () {
     this.render('home');
     Session.set('menu', 'home');
   }

   Router.route('/home', renderHome());
   Router.route('/abc/home', renderHome());
   ```

---

Can I instead do something like **specify an array, or comma-separated string**:

```
Router.route(['/home', '/abc/home'], function () {
  this.render('home');
  Session.set('menu', 'home');
});

// or

Router.route('/home, /abc/home', function () {
  this.render('home');
  Session.set('menu', 'home');
});
```

### How do I efficiently route multiple paths to one template, while not repeating myself?

Comment: Have you tried creating a regular expression (regex) that matches both `/home` and `/abc/home`?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone No I haven't tried that, looks like the way to go. Right now I'm using something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27456029/2317532, and will refactor later. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: OK, I added it as an answer so you can accept it. When you figure out the exact regular expression, let me know and I'll update my answer for future reference. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression (regex) that matches both `/home` and `/abc/home`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a second template that only includes the first. In your case this might look like this:

```
<template name="abcHome">
  {{> home}}
</template>
```