# Meteor Iron Router RegEx

Tags: regex, node.js, url, meteor, iron-router

I'm using **Iron Router** on my **Meteor** app, and I would like to know if using **regular expression** for defining route path is possible ?

Currently, I define path like this :

`path: '/article/:slug-:_id'`

But Iron router doesn't find the page, because of the `slug`, which contains dash too... so Iron router doesn't know how to identify `slug` and `id`

Is there any solution to define path more precisely ? Like in Symfony or Spring, etc :

`@Route("/article/{id}-{slug}", requirements={"id"="([0-9]+)", "slug"="([a-z0-9\-]+)"}, name="article_view")`

Many thanks !
Yannis.

Comment: Why not just use `/article/:slug/:id` ? Or are you trying to match a slug pattern from another system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using a regex in iron router, how to access the match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455206/when-using-a-regex-in-iron-router-how-to-access-the-match)

Comment: So, there is no way in Meteor to precisely define our routes... too bad.