# iron:router wildcard path generating seems to be broken

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When you create a wildcard URL in iron:router for meteor the pathFor Template helper but also Router.go and Router.routes[routeName].path() seems to be broken.

This is our route:

```
Router.route('/:urlQuery*', function(){
  this.render('ourTemplate');
}, {
  name : 'ourRoute',
});
```

To accessing a generated url to this we tried the following:

```
Router.go('ourRoute', {urlQuery : 'test'});
Router.go('ourRoute', {urlQuery : ['test']});
Router.go('ourRoute', {urlQuery : null});
Router.go('ourRoute', {urlQuery : false});

Router.routes.ourRoute.path({urlQuery : 'test'});
Router.routes.ourRoute.path({urlQuery : ['test']});
Router.routes.ourRoute.path({urlQuery : null});
Router.routes.ourRoute.path({urlQuery : false});
```

And - of course - also we tried the {{pathFor}} Template-Helper.

Every of these lines of code throw the same errors:

```
Uncaught Error: You are trying to access a wild card parameter at index 0 but the value of params at that index is undefined
```

I did not find any reference in the iron:router guide so my question is: How to generate a URL in iron:router with a wildcard as parameter ?

Comment: What's the * for on /:urlQuery*? I have not seen that, loks like your mixing params and regex paths?

Comment: This is the symbol for wildcard. So for example the route /test1/test2 would save "test1/test2" in the urlQuery param.

Comment: i've never seen that before. Are you perhaps thinking of regexs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455206/when-using-a-regex-in-iron-router-how-to-access-the-match

Comment: @ChristianFritz You can try this with * by your self. When using the route in my example you will get for this.params.urlQuery all arguments passing in the url at this place.

Comment: i see. interesting. is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Not in the official guide as I remember - but I have seen this example some where else and used it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Iron Router is using [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) but the format is a little different when used in Iron Router and not very clear. Try this...

```
Router.route('/:urlQuery(.*)', function(){
```

The (.*) will tell it to take the param name, and repeat it 0 or more times. Just urlQuery* is breaking the name I think, and making it part of the regex. Now if you want to pass an array of mulitple objects to Router.go, you will have another issue...

```
Router.go("our.route", {urlquery: ['test', 'another']});
```

Produces a URL that looks like this...

```
http://localhost:3000/test%2Canother
```

but that's a different issue I don't have an answer for yet. Perhaps for sending multiple's in Router.go, a better way would be to concat them yourself. Looks like iron router and path-to-regexp are not fully integrated  yet?